# Approximating integral of strange functions by rectangle method - Limit of errors

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We know if $f\in C^1\left[a,b\right]$, the error term of rectangle method 
$$R_n=\int_{a}^{b}fdx-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b-a}{n}f\left(a+\frac{k\left(b-a\right)}{n}\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
and my question is: we can construct a strange function $f$, differentiable everywhere, but having $R_n\ne O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Perhaps $f\left(x\right)=x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ on $\left[0,1\right]$ (defining $f\left(0\right)=0$ ) could  make it, but I’m not sure if I can prove it.

Comment: I think my answer was wrong. I didnt noticed the play of bounded variation here.

Comment: @Masacroso Anyway, we have a conclusion that if $f’$ is bounded, $nR_n$ must be bounded. So we only need to search for functions having unbounded derivatives.